# Update jtextfields in jpanel when other jtextfields changed

Tags: java, jpanel, jtextfield

i have a GUI with some jtextfields (for example jtextfield_a, jtextfield_b, jtextfield_c, jtextfield_d, jtextfield_e). I can't find a way to change the value of jtextfield_d and jtextfield_e when for example jtextfield_a value is changed. Any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you would write code that responds to events (since Swing is an *event*-driven GUI library), and then inside that code, change the state of the JTextField text.  Which event listeners you use will depend on which events you want to respond to (which you don't tell us). If you want more specific help, then you will want to write a more specific question, one that shows [mcve] code.

Comment: Note also that you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Answer (score 1):

## You could...

Use an `ActionListener` on the `JTextField` you want to monitor

See [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

### Cons

- Requires the user to press the "action" key (typically <kbd>Enter</kbd>) while the field is focused

## You could...

Use a `FocusListener` on the `JTextField` you want to monitor

### Cons

- Requires the user to leave the field, so the `focusLost` event can be triggered

See [How to Write a Focus Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) for more details

## You could...

Use a `DocumentListener` on the `JTextField` you want to monitor

See [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more details

### Pros

- Provides real time feedback as the user types

## You could...

Have some other control trigger the update, like a `JButton`, so the user gains greater control over the process.  It's not always the best from the users perspective (because we're lazy), but is among the simplest

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Just bunch of links to the tutorials - have a duplicate?